# Sitecore (version 8.2) Itemservice returns a 404 NotFound

Tags: sitecore-api, itemservice

As the title suggested, I'm getting a StatusCode NotFound (404).

Everything as far as I know has been setup correctly.

Been reading and following this to a T:

https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/sitecore-services-client.html

I can authenticate but when I try to retrieve or post an item I get NotFound statuscode.

Our solution has TDS and Glassmapper installed. I'm unaware of any issues caused by these but if anyone knows something please let me know.

At first I'd figured there might be something wrong with routing but as I said before I'm able to login. Or is this setup in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out on of the config files had an unneccesary patch which we didn't need.

```
  <excludedAssemblies hint="list:AddExcludedAssembly">
            <excludedAssembly id="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore" patch:after="excludedAssembly[@id='RazorGenerator.Mvc']">Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore</excludedAssembly>
          </excludedAssemblies>
```

After removing this AND obliberating the cache according to this post
[WebAPI Controllers not being found](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9897/webapi-controllers-not-being-found)

I was able to finally got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following setting in your `Sitecore.Services.Client.config` file.

Set the value for **Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy** setting as **ServicesOnPolicy**.

Check if the **ServicesAPI** user has Administrator access. You can do this in `User Manager-> ServicesAPI -> Edit -> enable the checkbox for Administrator`.

Comment: I did that.  Thanks but I've found the answer.